# Nautilus 3.26.4 crashes when pressing CTRL+N a few times in a row

Tags: 18.04, nautilus

When pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> a few times in a row Nautilus on Ubuntu 18.04 just crashes and all windows which were opened until the crash disappear. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Ctrl+N opens a new window. Does the rest of the system work fine or does the whole system "stop working"? And what do you exactly mean by "stop working"? Does it freeze? Does it closes itself? Does it stop rendering the icons on the Desktop?...

Comment: The system goes on working, but all windows, which were opened until the `stop` disappear. Maybe a better description is `crash` instead of `stop`

Comment: What's the time difference between successive pressing of Ctrl+N? I have observed in my main installation if I press Ctrl+N successively without any time delay, Nautilus crashes but if they are pressed waiting for a while to display folders and files, it doesn't crashes.

Comment: I confirm this observation.

Answer (score 2):

You encountered a bug with your version of Gnome Files, aka nautilus. In general, to help solve bugs, these should be reported to the developers. This issue in fact has been filed already to the developers, and has been investigated (https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/issues/722).

*Workaround*: take a little time opening new windows, and try not to open many at once.

*Resolution*: a new version of nautilus will ship with the forthcoming Ubuntu 19.04.